# How to pass CFData to C char**?

Tags: swift

From C, I need to call some Swift code which takes in an input byte array and produces an output byte array.

This is in the bridging header:

```
typedef void (*SwiftFunc)(const uint8_t* input, int inputLen, uint8_t** output, int* outputLen);

extern "C" void CFunc(SwiftFunc swiftFunc);
```

Here is the C implementation of CFunc:

```
void CFunc(SwiftFunc swiftFunc) {
    char* input = "Hello world";
    int inputLen = strlen(input);
    char* output = NULL;
    int outputLen = 0;
    swiftFunc(input, inputLen, &output, &outputLen);
    // do something with the output here
}
```

And here is the Swift code:

```
func swiftFunc(
    input: Optional<UnsafePointer<UInt8>>, 
    inputLen: Int32,
    output:Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<
             Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>>>>, 
    outputLen:Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>>) -> Void {

        let cfInput = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, input, CFIndex(inputLen))
        let cfOutput = ... generate the output ...

        How to pass the output buffer back to C?
}
```

How do I pass the output buffer from Swift to C? Given that a double pointer is involved.

Also the Swift function signature seems very verbose, is that expected?. I tried using `?` suffixes instead of `Optional<>` but the compiler didn't like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is set the `pointee` property of `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>>` to an instance of `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>`. With your current approach it is the Swift function's duty to allocate the memory associated with the output buffer.

Calling `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(MemoryLayout<UInt8>.stride * outputLength)` is roughly equivalent to calling `malloc`, and is necessary with this use case. After creating a buffer with the proper memory allocation, initialize its values from `cfOutput`. For example, if `cfOutput` was of type `[UInt8]` you could do the following:

```
for i in 0..<cfOutput.count {
    buf[i] = cfOutput[i]
}
```

After initializing the values within the output buffer, simply set `output?.pointee` to the `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>` you just allocated and initialized.

The following is an example of how you can pass the output buffer back to C.

```
func swiftFunc(input: UnsafePointer<UInt8>!,
               inputLen: Int32,
               output: UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<UInt8>>?,
               outputLen: UnsafePointer<UInt8>?) {
    let cfInput = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, input, CFIndex(inputLen))
    let cfOutput = // Generate your output.

    let bufLen = // Determine output buffer length.
    let buf = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(MemoryLayout<UInt8>.stride * bufLen)

    // Initialize 'buf' with 'cfOutput' somehow.

    output?.pointee = buf
    outputLen?.pointee = Int32(bufLen)
}
```